# Где нужны графы?

Tags: java, графы

Объясните кто-нибудь где следует применять эту структуру данных. Я изучаю java. Дошёл до изучения графов. Трудно что-то изучать, не понимая того, где я это смогу применить

Comment: Навигация, маршрутизация в сетях и т.п.

Comment: Состояния какой-то системы и переходы между ними - это тоже граф. Например, это может быть набор состояний приложения и переходов между ними (например, пользователь "что-то нажал" - открылось окошко, или начал скачиваться файл, и т.д.)

Comment: Могу посоветовать книгу "Алгоритмы. Вводный курс", Кормен. Она короткая, всего 200 страниц. В ней на понятных примерах рассказывается про графы.